# Magento Collection wrong result

Tags: php, sql, magento, collections, categories

i want to get the catageory path of a category.

I got the parent and the child name and i'm doing the following:

```
$categorys = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array("like" => $sCatName))
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getChildrenCategories()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array("like" => $sCatNameChild))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

I checked the result with echo `$categorys->getSelectSql();`

It returns the correct Sql, run it over sql return 1 cat (correct one)

I count the collection and there are 8 selected categorys in there ( all subs of the parent)

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you think should be returned?  it looks like you are trying to find the first parent category, and then find all the children with a specific name?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i am looking for. All parents habe a different name so there is always just 1 parent with differnet childs

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $id is the id of your category. You may get path like this
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$path = explode('/', $category->getPath());

I have not tested this code but it must work

Comment: i resolved the problem with another solution, getting the parent and then filter the child with foreach. I asked this question because the sql returned from collection is true but the mage result of collection is false